# How to compile the Swig examples?

Tags: java-native-interface, swig

I'm trying to use Swig between C and Java, and I've been able to write and run a simple test, but unable to write a C function that returns an array to Java, with either carrays.i or arrays_java.i. The examples given in the documentation are always incomplete and won't compile.

So I installed the examples (swig-examples) but I've been unable to compile them. For instance, in Examples/java/simple/:

```
$ make
make -f ../../Makefile SRCDIR='' SRCS='example.c' \
SWIG_LIB_DIR='' SWIGEXE='' \
SWIGOPT='' TARGET='example' INTERFACE='example.i' java
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/dargaud/test/Examples/java/simple'
make[1]: ../../Makefile: No such file or directory
make[1]: *** No rule to make target '../../Makefile'.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/dargaud/test/Examples/java/simple'
make: *** [Makefile:14: build] Error 2

$ ls ../..
android  contract  d   guile       java        lua          modula3   ocaml   perl5  pike    r       ruby    s-exp  test-suite
chicken  csharp    go  index.html  javascript  Makefile.in  mzscheme  octave  php    python  README  scilab  tcl    xml
```

There's no overall makefile, no configure script and the succinct documentation (README or index.html) doesn't mention how to compile it

Comment: The header in makefile.in says you need to have run configure to generate a makefile. Did you?

Comment: @Botje there's no configure. It's normally a script included with the packages, created by automake.

Comment: Looks like the Makefile.in needs some macro expansion to work (all the @foo@ stuff). It is probably best if you just grab a full tree of swig and run configure there..

Comment: @Botje Both the tar.gz and the git repo (https://github.com/swig/swig/tree/master/Examples) are the same: no configure scripts or makefiles.

Comment: There is an `autogen.sh` script at the top level that will run `autoconf` for you to generate a `configure` and run it

Comment: Thanks, didn't notice it. That worked: `autogen.sh &&  ./configure && make && cd Examples/java/simple && make`